# Django. Get values from related table using .all() query without re-querying the DB

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Quick caveat - I am quite new to Django, web development, and programming in general so I fully expect to be doing some stupid things. I am running into an issue where I am querying the DB far too many times, resulting in 50 duplicates. I want to be able to do one large query, that fetches all results, and then be able to pull from that query as needed. I have tried to make this happen, but I cannot seem to figure out how to specify a value in my prefetched query without recalling the query again.

My understanding is that `.all()` doesn't necessarily call the query at the point of declaration, and I'm guessing that is my issue, but I'm not sure. Here is my code:

```
qs = Employees.objects.all().select_related(
            'employee', 'team', 'department', 'manager')
for p in periods:
    period, range, score, subject = p
    current_team = current_department = current_manager = None
    try:
        user = qs.get(employee_id=subject)
        current_team = user.team
        current_department = user.department
        current_manager = user.manager.username
        subject = user.employee.username
    except (User.DoesNotExist, Employees.DoesNotExist):
        subject = User.objects.get(id=subject).username
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution: Decided to turn the `qs` into a list which fetches it immediately and then iterate through that list to not execute any more queries:

```
qs = list(Employees.objects.all().select_related('employee', 'team', 'department', 'manager'))

for q in qs:
    if subject == q.employee_id:
        current_team = q.team
        current_department = q.department
        current_manager = q.manager.username
        subject = q.employee.username
    else:
        subject = subject
```

Answer (score 0):

You have come across `n+1` issue.

The django way to fetch the related records for one-to-many relationship and avoid `n+1` issue is to use `select_related`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

**Without `select_related`:**

Hits the database.

```
e = Entry.objects.get(id=5)
```

Hits the database again to get the related Blog object.

```
b = e.blog
```

**With `select_related`:**

Hits the database.

```
e = Entry.objects.select_related('blog').get(id=5)
```

Doesn't hit the database, because e.blog has been prepopulated
in the previous query.

```
b = e.blog
```

Comment: I don't think this would solve my issue, unless I am misunderstanding. My issue is that I have several `id` in this example. So I have tried to use `select_related` for the entire table objects, and then specify which `id` I need when I need it. But by doing so, it has made it difficult to not requery the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand your schema from the example. However, coercing a [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference) into a list won't scale well, neither will looping over the model. Instead try passing a list of `employee_ids` to the field lookup [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
employee_ids = [p[3] for p in periods]
employees = Employees.objects.filter(employee_id__in=employee_ids)
```

or the opposite:

```
employees = Employees.objects.exclude(employee_id__in=employee_ids)
```